# How to by default return 405 method not allowed when wrong HTTP method is used for given URL?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

It looks like Play returns 404 when you want to access URL with wrong HTTP method. In Django there is a possibility to use `require_http_methods` decorator where you can place HTTP methods which can be used with given view and when wrong method is used then 405 is returned. Is there some easy way to specify in Play routes file or somewhere else to return 405 method not allowed response when wrong method was used (for example POST instead of GET) - without doing explicit controller handler for each URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(Http.RequestHeader uri) {
        Iterator<Tuple3<String, String, String>> it = Routes.documentation().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if(it.next()._2().equals(uri.uri())){
                return new Results.Status(play.core.j.JavaResults.MethodNotAllowed(), "Your msg", Codec.javaSupported("utf-8"));
            }
        }
        return super.onHandlerNotFound(uri);
    }

}
```